# Eclipse C: "Function cannot be resolved" errors aren't raised

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

While editing `C programs` in `Eclipse 2022-12` it doesn't raise any obvious unresolved function errors while it is able to do it with unresolved symbols.

In `Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Code Analysis > Configure Workspace Settings...` the `Syntax and Semantic Errors > Function cannot be resolved` is ticked.
It is also set to `Run as you type` and `Run on demand`.
I also checked that in `Code Analysis > Launching` `Run as you type` is ticked.

I rebuilt the Index of my project.

What Eclipse uses to raise this kind of warning and what can I do to make it raising it?